# Book about persecuted group fleeing earth, finding and settling new planet, new life, get hunted down by earth persecutors

Tags: story-identification, spaceship, religion, space-exploration

Read a book in the mid 2000s about a group that was persecuted, Christians I believe, that accidentally discovered FTL travel. They built a ship and left Earth. They discovered a new planet, and filled with new plant and wildlife. However, they found they were still pursued, even after leaving Earth.

Comment: *Last Train from Earth: An Escape from Tyranny* matches what you're looking for, but it was published in 2015.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This might be James F. David's *[Judgment Day](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/634274.Judgment_Day)*, published in 2005.

[image: Book cover - *Judgment Day*]

> Kingdom of Light; The Forces of Darkness
>
> Ira Breitling---Man of God; Manuel Crow---Lord of Darkness
>
> Even the universe is not big enough for the both of them . . . especially when Ira Breitling is handed a divine gift---an interstellar engine that can lift humanity into the heavens. Crow---awash in riches, commanding nations, supremely powerful---swears eternal vengeance on Breitling and his Fellowship of the Faithful . . . and on all humankind.
>
> The reign of Lucifer---prophesized as a thousand years of darkness---is about to begin. With the world falling fast under Crow's violent sway, Breitling's Fellowship---having only one choice---seizes their divine gift, their faster-than-light flight, and flees the earth. Their journey takes them beyond the distant stars to a perfect planet uncorrupted by Crow and his Kingdom of Darkness.
>
> But even as Manuel Crow razes and racks the Earth, Revelations' scourge is not yet sated. Crows eyes the heavens, fixed on the Faithful.
>
> Ira Breitling and the Fellowship must defend not only themselves but the soul of all humanity: A Kingdom of Light against the Forces of Darkness. Will the Fellowship prevail . . . or fall under Revelations' reign?
>
> Let the battle begin.

I found it by searching for *science fiction novel christians develop FTL to escape persecution*

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've been trying to find the answer to this for years searching various things. I will also be checking out the other book you mentioned. Thanks!